# changes in position of images in tinymce editor is not taking exact position in preview

Tags: jquery, image, tinymce, editor, draggable

while changing the position of image in tinymce editor, it is not taking exact position in preview.

[image]

```js
 tinymce.init({selector: "textarea",branding: false,  force_br_newlines : true,
      'setup' : function(ed) {
      ed.on('init', function(e) {
      $(ed.getBody()).on("click", "img", function() {
      $(this).draggable();
      });

      });
      },paste_data_images: true,  images_upload_url: '/user/dashboard/upload',
      theme: "modern",width:"100%",height :'300px',forced_root_block : "",plugins: ["pagebreak advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak","searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen","insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu imagetools directionality","emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"],
      paste_block_drop:true,
      menubar: "edit table",
      toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | pagebreak",
      toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",image_advtab: true,templates: [{title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},{title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}],
      pagebreak_separator: "<div class='page-break'></div>",



      images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
      var xhr, formData;

      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.withCredentials = false;
      xhr.contentType= false;
      xhr.processData= false;
      xhr.open('POST', '/user/dashboard/upload');

      xhr.onload = function() {
      var json;
     
      if (xhr.status != 200) {
       failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
       return;
      }
      json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
       failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
       return;
      }

      success(json.location);

      };
      var token = $('#token').val();
      formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('_token',token);
      formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
      xhr.send(formData);
      }


    });


    // This code is used for insert google chart inside tinymce editor  
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    tinymce.get("description").execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 
    chart_div.innerHTML);
    });
```

I have set 3 images in one line, but it is not showing the images in exact place. It is showing in preview one image is on another image. Above i have mentioned the code.

Comment: Without seeing the exact HTML that you are loading into the editor (along with the CSS) it will be very hard to provide any help.  Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/) that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: I have added the code into fiddle.tinymce. But for image upload you need to write a code  to work the functionality. You can click on google chart button to create a chart inside the tinymce editor. Once you finished with writing image upload code, Image can be movable inside the editor. Please insert 3-4 images inside the editor and move it, then check the preivew. If any more information required. Please tell me. @MichaelFromin

Comment: TinyMCE Fiddle http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gsgaab